# How to get current month from json before making a calculation

Tags: arrays, vue.js, date, vuejs2

I need to make a calculation based on the objects numberTerminations and totalNumberActiveUnits from this dataset. When choosing numberTerminations, I need to make sure that it only picks the current month from the date field.

[image]

I started making the code for it, but I am not sure how to actually get the month.
I know there is a getMonth function that I can use in Vue, but where am I supposed to put it?

```js
created(){
    biService.getBIGraphStatsForCompany()
        .then(result => result.data.propertyStatsPerMonth.forEach(field => {
          this.chartData.datasets[0].data.push(Math.round(field.numberTerminations / result.data.totalNumberActiveUnits * 100))
        }))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
```

Comment: [getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is not specific to Vue, it's vanilla JS on the Date object.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by getting the current month, since that's what you're going to use to filter your results.

Then, you should use the `.filter` function on the array to find the result you're looking for.

I don't really know what the `forEach` loop is for. Is there a possiblity of more than one result matching the current month?

```
created(){
    // Start by getting the current month.
    // N.B. - getMonth counts months starting at 0, i.e. January - month 0
    const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth()

    biService.getBIGraphStatsForCompany()
        .then((result) => {
            const data = result.data.propertyStatsPerMonth.find(row => new Date(row.date) === currentMonth;

            // use data to do your calculations
        }))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
```

Comment: I added forEach because I need to go through the objects in the propertyStatsPerMonth array, in this case to locate the numberTerminations field.

Comment: But in your question you said "When choosing numberTerminations, I need to make sure that it only picks the current month from the date field." - That, to me, implies that you only want the one result. My code will return that one single row, and you will be able to access your `numberTerminations` property.